# meaning "to outshine" but for a sound

Tags: single-word-requests

We say that a light source *shines*, and that one source may *out-shine* another.  Is there an equivalent term for a sound, that does not include a negative connotation?  For example, "Her voice was able to [outshine] all others in the room."

If we wanted to convey that one sound *outshined* another, we might say, [*drown-out* or *shout-over*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209733/word-for-to-speak-louder-than), but again either *drown* or *shout* has negative, harsh connotations.  The only analogous term to shine, but for sounds, that I can think of is *to ring*.  But there is no obvious *out-ring* version.

---

This is not the same as ["To camouflage" is to sight as "to ____" is to sound](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/409312/to-camouflage-is-to-sight-as-to-is-to-sound), because *"outshine"*---the be brighter, more visible---is distinct from *"camouflage"*---to hide, disguise, or coverup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["To camouflage" is to sight as "to \_\_\_\_" is to sound](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/409312/to-camouflage-is-to-sight-as-to-is-to-sound): 'What could be used for hiding one sound under another?'

Comment: Not a single word, but we often use height or layering metaphors with sound: "Her voice *could be heard **over*** all others in the room" or, to use *ring*, "her voice *rang (out) **above*** all others in the room" etc.

Comment: OP in the question with the answer broadens the question to  'What could be used for hiding one sound under another?'  As there is no prescription there on a negative tenor, 'drown out' is offered, but the question includes the non-negative case. 'Mask' is suggested. // 'Eclipsed' has no or not much negative connotation, but is a poor metaphor for sound.

Comment: In audio, presence and prominence are often used to express sound quality usually in comparison to/with others.

Answer (score 2):

There is the notion of *raising one's voice* so as to be heard. So, perhaps ***transcend*** would be a suitable synonym to choose.

> :to outstrip or outdo in some attribute, quality, or power
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transcend)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any such single word in English.

The closest terms would probably be "drown out," "overwhelm," or "bury," all of which have the negative connotations that the OP seeks to avoid; and "overpower," which, with its broad range of applications, is less finely tuned to sensory stimuli than "outshine" is.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider ***overshadow*** which is generic and not really specific to *sound*.

> "Her voice was able to ***overshadow*** all others in the room."

ODO:

> **[overshadow](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/overshadow)** *VERB*
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> **2** **Appear much more prominent or important than.**
>   ‘his competitive nature often overshadows the other qualities’

Usage examples *in the context of **voice***:

> [Google search for "overshadow other voices".](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22overshadow%20other%20voices%22)
>   [Google search for "overshadows other voices".](https://www.google.com/search?dcr=0&biw=1707&bih=813&q=%22overshadows%20other%20voices%22)
>   **Note**: some of them
>   use *voice* in the figurative sense of *opinion*.

Comment: Thanks, I like this suggestion.  I also appreciate the irony that it is still based (explicitly) on a visual metaphor!

Answer (score 0):

The word ***outsing*** might be what you're looking for:

> 'She was able to outsing all others in the room'.

According to the [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/outsing) it means 'to sing better or louder than someone else'.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outsing) defines it as 'to outdo or surpass in singing'.

I've heard it used in (UK) folk-singing circles and in choirs.

Answer (score 0):

The word *resound* just came to me as a good possibility, google says (emphasis added),

> re·sound
>   / rəˈzound /
>
> 1. (of a sound, voice, etc.) **fill a place with sound; be loud enough to echo**. "another scream resounded through the school" synonyms: echo, re-echo, reverberate, ring out, boom, thunder, rumble "the explosion resounded around the silent street"
> 2. literary sing (the praises) of. "Horace resounds the praises of Italy"

My impression is that *resound* would be a good sonic equivalent to *shine*, which implicitly includes the sense of *out-shining* --- at least enough to still be clearly discernible.