# Alternative for "overshout" somebody/something

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm confused. I need to say: attempting to overshout the noise would quickly get me hoarse. But I can't see the word "overshout" used anywhere. Is overshout an understandable word? Or would "shout over" make any difference? What other way should I say it, meaning to shout louder at the same time than somebody/something in order to be heard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While "overshout" might be understood, it would be more idiomatic to use "shout over" or "shout above". Both prepositions are used, with "shout over" being slightly more common:

> - We had to shout over the noise of the traffic.
> - We had to shout above the noise of the traffic.
>     <sub>[Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/noise)</sub>

---

"Yell" can also be used this way:

- > [I have to yell over the wind](https://books.google.com/books?id=4jdGBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT116&lpg=PT116&dq=%22yell+over+the%22&source=bl&ots=yOdzWTFko3&sig=JC3sWVw-7gqsCFiiRbcD4SV5MX0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTzPaEi8DaAhXim-AKHelRArQ4ChDoAQgrMAE#v=onepage&q=%22yell%20over%20the%22&f=false)
- > [Southern resident orcas must yell above the din](http://www.islandsweekly.com/news/southern-resident-orcas-must-yell-above-the-din/)

Comment: You answered all of my questions :-)

Answer (score 1):

**shout down** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/shout+down)

as a phrasal Verb:

> To overwhelm or silence by shouting loudly.

Comment: Not necessarily to silence or to make someone feel overwhelmed because of me shouting at them. Actually the word I seek doesn't have that meaning at all.

Answer (score 1):

speak over

If there's loud music playing and you want to talk to someone you'd need to speak over the ambient music. Same as other loud conversations in the background, you may need to speak over them to be heard.

I can't provide definitions because neither are idioms, they're just ordinary expressions/collocations of words understood by parsing the words.

You can also speak over someone if you're louder than them or no allowing them to fully express themselves.

> There was a lot of whispering, and feet moving. Churchill had a soft
>   voice so it was hard to speak over the noise.
>   [Link](https://prezi.com/knzdhhepf4l3/winston-chuchill-we-shall-fight-on-the-beaches/)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to say "shout over" and "shout above" because of these references:

**Shout above:**

https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/world-news/dolphins-shout-above-noise-passing-5577324

> Dolphins have to 'shout' above noise of passing ships to communicate
>   says study

**Shout over:**

https://www.livescience.com/6705-whales-shout-noise-pollution.html

> Say What?! Whales Shout over Noise Pollution

[Word for "to speak louder than"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209733/word-for-to-speak-louder-than)

```
If you're trying to talk to a friend during a loud concert, you might say "I had to shout over the music".
```